# Toggle Button in Eclipse Forms Section Toolbar

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

How do I implement a toggle button, as pictured below, in the section toolbar of Eclipse UI Forms?
I only find examples for adding actions to the section toolbar.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think the key is: `IAction.AS_CHECK_BOX`

```
    toggleBotton = new Action(Messages.toolTipMessage, IAction.AS_CHECK_BOX) {
        @Override
        public void run() {

        }
    };

    toggleBotton.setImageDescriptor(...);
    toggleBotton.setEnabled(...);
    getManagedForm().getForm().getToolBarManager().add(toggleBotton);
```